# Using a form to display users name on every page till the user logs out

Tags: php, session

I am currently creating a website that will allow the user to log in using a username only, no password is required. Once the user has typed their name into the form, their name should then be placed on all of the pages they then visit until they log out.

I am having problems with this as it, 1) Not showing in the browser correctly (*I will provide images below*) 2) Not forwarding me to the Home Page.

```
<?php
session_save_path("/aber/sec17/public_html/cs25010/tmp");
session_start();
if ($username == NULL) {
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
    header("Location: home.php");
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sean Coyne's Food Shop</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Sean Coyne's Food Shop" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Sean Coyne's Food Shop" 
title="Sean Coyne's Food Shop" width="400px" height="70px"/>

</div>

        <div id="nav">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="database.php">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="drink.php.html">Offers</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="findus.php">Where to find us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div id="main">
            <h1>Welcome to Sean Coyne's Food Shop</h1>
            <h2>Please Log In below:</h2>
            <br></br>
            <div id="login">
                <?php
                    echo '<form action="home.php" method"post"> 
                    <input type="text" name="username" text="input username"
                    placeholder="Username" required> 
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
                    </form>';
                ?>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the login page:

[image: Screenshot of the log in page]

Comment: have you added session_save_path("/aber/sec17/public_html/cs25010/tmp");
session_start(); in all php pages?

Comment: This is not a login feature.. Don't use it to show sensitive data..

Comment: There is a session_start() on all of my other pages.

Comment: What this "$username" variable holds?

Comment: The "$username" will hold anything that is typed into the form, then i should be able to call "$username" on other pages to display what they typed using sessions, I believe that is correct anyway.

Comment: I can see php code in that screenshot, which suggests either 1) You have a syntax error or 2) Your server is not set up to process php and is just outputting the source code as plain text, hence nothing is working. Right click and select 'view source' and see what you get. Can you see the php code?

Comment: Then replace if($username ==  NULL) with if(empty($_SESSION['username']) and then check

Answer (score 0):

Needless to introduce the form labels "php" change this;

```
<?php
    echo '<form action="home.php" method"post"> 
    <input type="text" name="username" text="input username"
    placeholder="Username" required> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
    </form>';
?>
```

For this:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="POST"> 
        <input type="text" name="username" text="input username" placeholder="Username" required /> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: This has created a error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /ceri/homes1/s/sec17/public_html/cs25010/index.php on line 52

Comment: He's trying to redirect twice to send the form in its action attribute and indicates that it will go to home.php , however the need to first fence at the head of the file to initialize the session , so let the action of empty form, the form is HTML, there is no reason for this in php tags

Answer (score 0):

If this is your complete file, then you may need to check your if condition. Replace the condition:

```
if ($username == NULL)
```

with:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['username']))
```

and try